# Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly? For ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pgadmin

i'm trying to run pgAdmin on ubuntu using using docker and currently i'm getting this error : `Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?`

Any solution ?